# Angular 6 web application integration with Django server

Tags: django, angular

I am developing a new web application using Angular 6 with Django as my backend server. Please share me the resources on how to proceed further and what is the best way to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always I use Angular for front-end and Django for back-end I use [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for building a REST API you can consume from Angular.

And some times I deploy such solution apart (a server for Angular and a separate server for Django, this is the way I prefer) or use django-webpack and run all the solution as you were running only a Django project. See how is done in this [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Django is not server.
[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a Object-Relational Mapper.

I think you are new to web development. Go through [this](https://engineering.videoblocks.com/web-architecture-101-a3224e126947) .

Create separate repositories for frontend and backend.
I have built two to three projects by same tech stack you prefer, you can check
the [frontend](https://github.com/AjayShelar/Frontend) and [backend](https://github.com/AjayShelar/backend) of one of my project.

Good way to go will be, use Django as ORM  and web framework too. As Django is tightly coupled with its ORM. Also build your rest apis using [django-rest](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) .
Use [uWsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) to deploy you web application.

Angular will call your apis to do CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) Operations.